# Is it possible to get a edition number from a compressed NFT?

Tags: compression

Given 10 compressed NFTs would it be possible to get a serial number of mint number for these tokens? I'm not seeing it in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

No, currently cNFTs are 1/1's and not created as editions. If you wanted to serialize them in that way you'd want to have something in the metadata of each (in the name, or as an attribute).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the NFT standard used in Solana ecosystem includes the mint number as a specific field.

However, the most popular tool for minting and distribuiting NFT collections on Solana is Candy Machine and it is configured to add the mint number to the name of the NFT (eg *The Heist #4743*) so this could be considered an informal standard.

For reading cNFTs in general, because the NFT data is not stored in accounts (but in ledger history) you need to use a [special RPC](https://docs.solana.com/developing/guides/compressed-nfts#using-the-read-api) to get this info.